# Tag modification A350 vs A350XWB

Tags: discussion

The current tag [airbus-a350](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a350) refers not to the old Airbus A350 project but to the current A350XWB model in operation since 2014.

I propose to rename the current tag to airbus-a350XWB and create a new one that refers to the previous project, airbus-a350.

Comment: This sounds like overkill.

Answer (score 6):

Do we expect to get that many questions specifically about the initial A350 design?

It seems like [airbus-a350](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a350) fits our current convention and would be clear enough that it refers to the production version. Questions about the initial design seem to be related enough to use the same tag.

There might be a case when there are multiple production versions of a plane, but we just have one [boeing-737](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-737) tag and one [airbus-a320](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a320) tag, with no A330 tag, let alone a separate neo tag.

Answer (score 6):

I actually think changing the tag would be *more* likely to cause confusion. If someone comes here with a question and there are two different tags, they may pick [airbus-a350](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a350) because that's the name they know, or they may be confused by the multiple tags to pick from.

To my knowledge, no examples of the original design were even built, and the design was abandoned almost a decade ago. The likelihood of us getting many (if any) questions on it is pretty low.

Furthermore, as fooot points out, we don't include variants in tag names. We don't have [boeing-737-100](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-737-100), [boeing-737-200](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-737-200), [boeing-737-300](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-737-300), etc, or [boeing-737-next-generation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-737-next-generation) or [boeing-737-max](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-737-max). We just have one [boeing-737](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-737) tag. If the volume of questions ever warrants splitting them up, we can consider that then.

I don't see why the Airbus A350 should get special treatment in this matter.

Comment: well... there is a tag for A320 and A319 which are variants. I agree with comment about the previous model, but concerning the current model its name is actually A350xwb and not a350

Comment: I'm all about precision in tags, but [even Wikipedia generally ignores the original (aborted) A350 project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A350_(disambiguation)), so I'm comfortable with doing the same and blaming…er, *claiming* them as the precedent :)

Comment: XWB represents the family of aircraft, not really the model name. It represents the A350-800, -900, and -1000 models. The model names themselves are not called the "A350XWB-800" etc. This is similar to the Boeing 737 NG which represented a family of models, but isn't actually a model name itself. Source: http://www.airbus.com/aircraftfamilies/passengeraircraft/a350xwbfamily/