# Do we need a separate [airbus-a319] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[This question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1592/755) brought to my attention that, as of 2 months ago, there is now an [airbus-a319](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a319) tag. It has exactly 2 questions and no tag wiki. For nearly all, if not all, other aircraft types, we do not have individual tags for the different models, even across different generations.

Is there really a need for a separate [airbus-a319](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a319) tag or should we just retag its two questions with [airbus-a320](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a320)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just (unilaterally, sorry) created synonyms. [airbus-a321](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a321) and [airbus-a319](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a319) now point to [airbus-a320](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a320). They're the same type, and there's no value in doing the same thing for, say, 737-700.